# How to copy QString into wchar_t buffer

Tags: c++, qt

I am using an old API that requires pointer to a char array for a file name.

I want to make the names dynamically so I use something like this:

```
QString fileName = QString("./TestImage_%1_%2.bmp")
        .arg(static_cast<int>(position)).arg(imgCounter++);
```

Then I create a new array on the heap each time I need to save a file:

```
wchar_t* array = new wchar_t[fileName.length() + 1];
fileName.toWCharArray(array);
array[fileName.length()] = 0;
ImageFileParams.pwchFileName = array; // API uses this to write the file
// ... rest of the code
```

The I delete the array:

```
delete[] array;
```

This allocation and deletion of the memory is a bit funny in 2019...so I declared a class member buffer like this:

```
/** Buffer to hold dynamic names for use with IDS API*/
wchar_t mNameBuffer[256] = {'\0'};
```

The question now is, how can I copy the content of my dynamic QString into this buffer and pass the pointer to the API call?

Comment: try fileName.toWCharArray(mNameBuffer);

Comment: @rafaelgonzalez hahahah that was too easy :D :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're going to be modern, be modern:

```
std::wstring t = fileName.toStdWString();
ImageFileParams.pwchFileName = t.c_str();
```

No need to guess at buffer sizes.